# Scheduling a process in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a simple serverless architecture in AWS that processes incoming requests.
An API Gateway receives a request and sends it to a lambda. The lambda saves the request to a Dynamodb and then moves the request to an SQS for further processing  (other lambdas will listen to the SQS).

Some of the requests received by the API GW include a time stamp that indicates when it should be processed (can be up to 24 hours).

I’m looking for a safe and efficient way to schedule those requests to be processed.

What did I look into:

Cloudwatch/ event scheduler are not a good fit as I see as it will pass the schedule responsibility to the Lambda. Meaning, the lambda will have many specific schedules. It doesn’t sound a great fit

Delayed SQS Messages has limited delay time. It doesn’t fit my 24 hours requirement.

I could manage the schedule myself by running a query on DynamoDB every minute and check if there are requests ready to be processed. I don’t like this solution as it sounds very wasteful.

How would you suggest to schedule the incoming requests to be processed?

Comment: I think the delayed SQS message is the way to go. Even if it's maximum delay is shorter than 24 hours you can have the consumer re-send it to the queue with a new delay that fits your requirement.

Comment: @Christian I don't think that SQS delays (that have a maximum of 15 minutes) works is observed when connected to an AWS Lambda function.

Comment: It doesn’t sound like SQS delay is the way to go, if AWS wanted us to use it this way they would allow a longer period of time

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to schedule a delayed execution using a [`Wait` state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html). The maximum execution time of a Step Function workflow is 1 year. Please have a look at this [example of a task timer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/task-timer-sample.html) for implementation details.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does AWS Simple Workflow also fit the OP's use case? Or is SWF an overkill? (not too familiar with SWF, I happen to be in a similar situation)

Comment: Yes, you can use SWF, too. However, you should consider using AWS Step Functions for all your new applications, since it provides a more productive and agile approach to coordinating application components using visual workflows. With Amazon SWF, instead of writing state machines in declarative JSON, you write a decider program to separate activity steps from decision steps. This provides you complete control over your orchestration logic, but increases the complexity of developing applications.

Answer (score 1):

For times < 15 minutes, you can use SQS message timers.

For times greater than 15 minutes, you can poll DynamoDB every 15 minutes, and then forward messages to SQS with a message timer when they're supposed to be sent before the next poll.

Polling every 15 minutes is only 3000 polls per month -- very cheap.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this solution. I usually prefer to avoid using crontabs. You can get to a certain percussion (you suggest a 15 minutes). If possible I would like to use a more elegant solution.

Comment: You get excellent precision, because when a poll sends the message, it sends it with a timer for the remaining time.

Comment: I see what you mean. There might be an issue with a new request scheduled to 5 minutes from now. Since the poll runs every 15 minutes, this transaction won’t be executed on time

Comment: When you schedule a task for less than 15 minutes from now, you send it to SQS right away.